# Мы первые или мы первыми?

Tags: местоимения

Между мной и мной возник спор, как же все-таки правильно "Мы первыЕ начали переход трубопроводов" или "Мы первыМИ начали переход трубопроводов"?

Мы первыми в городе начали переход трубопроводов через дороги методом «прокалывания». 
Первыми стали устанавливать системы воздушного отопления.

Хотелось бы с пояснениями и правилами. К сожалению, через поиск ничего не нашла.

Comment: Во-первых, неправильно построена фраза "начали переход трубопроводов через дороги". 

Можно тогда правильный вариант?

П.С: огромное спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: Что такое "прокалывание"? Это разве не мостовой переход? Тогда EkaterinaKas... права. Хотя может быть еще туннельный...

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, неправильно построена фраза "начали переход трубопроводов через дороги". 
Во-вторых, "начали первые" или "начали первыми" - составное именное сказуемое, которое можно употребить и в той, и в другой форме. У нас ПЕРВЫЕ - порядковое числительное, которое склоняется как прилагательное.

*Имя прилагательное* в роли **именной части сказуемого** употребляется в полной и краткой формах, в формах разных степеней. Для прилагательных полной формы характерны и ***именительный и творительный падежи.***  ....Именная часть может быть выражена **именем числительным** или количественно-именным сочетанием. Например: ... ***Сережка **был первый**,*** кто их увидел ***(Фад.); **Первым***** пришел дед ***(Пауст.).***[здесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-015.htm)

Comment: >начали переход трубопроводов через дороги

Это профжаргон. "Переход" - здесь конструкция. Можно придраться лишь к тому, можно ли "начать конструкцию" или её строительсво.

Answer (score 1):

Интуитивно напрашивается "первыми". "Мы первыми (сделали что-либо)". В отличие от "Мы - первые (в каком-либо деле, сфере деятельности)".

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере эти конструкции равнозначны, то есть можно употребить и так и так.
Но не всегда они взаимозаменяемы. 
Например: Пол-, полу- являются *первыми* частями сложных слов. — Здесь нельзя употребить "первые".
Следовательно, выбор формы зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта, но разница в употреблении им. или вин.падежа всё же есть. 
Именит. падеж в составном именном сказуемом характеризует постоянный признак, творительный – непостоянный. Он был добрый человек (всегда добрый),но возможно и Он был добрым.Он был парикмахером. - непост. признак. Но возможно сказать: Он был настоящий парикмахер.(В облике этого человека превалируют качества парикмахера).Он был учителем средней школы.(непост.) НО: Он был настоящий учитель!(пост.)
 В Вашем случае всё-таки признак непостоянный, значит, верно будет в творит. падеже. Начали переход какими?-первыми.
Мы первые начали - появляется оттенок превосходства, хвастовства, кот. возможен в бытовом разговоре, но не в письменной речи.
Не лучше так: "Мы первыми начали прокладывание (вместо "переход") трубопроводов..."?

Answer (score 1):

При абсолютной грамматической правильности обоих вариантов (согласен с EkaterinaKas...) я бы предпочел вариант "первыми". Вариант с именительным падежом хуже воспринимается на слух в контрукциях с придаточным и тяготеет только к абсолютной конструкции: "Он был первый".